# Cannot resolve constructor 'BarEntry(int.java.lang.CharSequence)' in MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to show date time on xAxis for my bar chart. I got this data from my UNIX timestamp firebase database. I try to convert this UNIX timestamp to a human-readable date. I have created an object in Kotlin to convert that UNIX timestamp to a human-readable date. This is my object:

```
package com.example.creategraph

import android.text.format.DateFormat
import java.util.*

object DateHelper {
//lateinit var Obj: DateHelper

fun fromString(pattern: String, d: Long): CharSequence? {
    return  DateFormat.format(pattern, Date(d*1000))
  }
}
```

However, when I use this object into my method it comes up with the error: Cannot resolve constructor BarEntry(int.java.lang.CharSequence). Here is my method:

```
 private void retrievedata() {
    weightReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<BarEntry> dataValue = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                for (DataSnapshot myDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    datapoint DataPoint = myDataSnapshot.getValue(datapoint.class);
                    dataValue.add(new BarEntry(DataPoint.getDate(), DateHelper.INSTANCE.fromString("dd-MM-yyyy",(DataPoint.getValue())));

                }
                showChart(dataValue);

            } else {
                chart.clear();
                chart.invalidate();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

`

The error message is located at dataValue.add(new BarEntry(DataPoint.getDate(), DateHelper.INSTANCE.fromString("dd-MM-yyyy",(DataPoint.getValue())));

Comment: don't use `new` keyword in kotlin

Comment: If you use MPAndroidChart , BarEntry constructor(float,float). you cannot use char. So you should xAxis.setValueFormatter to show date.

Comment: I have tried to use setValueFormatter, but I got incorrect results like overlaps chart and every bar show the same date. Would you like to give me a reference for this formatter? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you update your question.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/kasimoz/Exchange_Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kasim/exchangeandroid/chartFormatter/DateChartFormatter.kt) is my formatter.

Comment: I'm sorry couldn't find  toStringFormat() in helpers

Comment: You should put your DateHelper method. That's my method.

Comment: I have update my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61667774/how-to-set-string-value-of-date-time-on-xaxis-bar-chart-mpandroid-chart